# Ubuntu home login page is not visible

Tags: login

I am using dual boot on my laptop. when I start Ubuntu then login page is not visible and when I start via recovery mode then it's working fine. Kindly help with this.

Thank you

Comment: We currently have little detail to help you with, we don't know what Ubuntu product/release your using (*a desktop system maybe but you haven't said*) nor what release of that *unstated* product you're using.  Was it just installed? or an older install?  Were any changes made in the last session where you had normal behavior (*its common for changes to be visible on next or subsequent boots so details are always helpful*), do you use it regularly (*how regularly; as that provides clues as to what updates may be involved etc*)....   The more we know the more we can help.

Comment: Help: What do your logs say about the problem?

Comment: I am unable to open in safe mode I have always started via recovery mode. When I tried to open it in safe mode the screen showed black and the login interface is missing